# set cookie in incognito browser window through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

not able to set cookie through chrome extension using the below code in the incognito window.

```
chrome.cookies.set(
    {
      name: 'test_cookie',
      value: JSON.stringify({name: 'some-test'}),
      secure: true,
      sameSite: 'no_restriction',
      url,
      path: '/',
      domain: getCookieDomain(new URL(url).hostname),
      expirationDate: Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1.86e6).getTime() / 1000)
    },
    console.log
  );
```

the same code works fine in normal chrome window. I'am using the manifest v3 for the extension development & incognito is set to spanning mode in manifest & cannot be set to split or not_allowed.

Comment: Add `storeId: '1'` to set the cookie for the incognito profile.

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, It worked setting the cookie in the incognito Mode. Now to set in both the normal Mode and Incognito mode i have tried some like below.

Answer (score 0):

```
  chrome.cookies.getAllCookieStores()
  .then( async cookieStores => {

    const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true });
    
    const storeId = cookieStores?.find( cookieStore => cookieStore?.tabIds?.indexOf(tab?.id) !== -1)?.id;

    chrome.cookies.set(
      {
        name: 'test_cookie',
        value: JSON.stringify({name: 'some-test'}),
        secure: true,
        sameSite: 'no_restriction',
        url,
        path: '/',
        domain: getCookieDomain(new URL(url).hostname),
        expirationDate: Math.floor(new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1.86e6).getTime() / 1000),
        storeId
      },
      console.log
    );
  })
```

To set cookies in both normal mode and incognito mode, we could try something like this. Get all the cookie stores available, and check current tab is part of which cookie store and then set the cookie in that store.